# Using an auth token in Angular from the .net core mvc 2.2 app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

The scenario is I am using an existing asp.net core mvc 2.2 application. 
Has the built authentication and functionality.

I however find myself writing a lot of javascript for dom manipulation and ajax querying.

I would like to use angular on certain views for my own personal reasons.

With all due respect before getting into the debate on mixing angular and mvc, I would like to know if and how is it possible to grant a token to angular so it can cache it, so all api calls are secure.

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials on web. [This](https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login) and [This](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api) for example.

Comment: Thanks - my question is more along the lines of after the normal mvc authentication to almost get a token and inject to angular. if that makes any sense...